# Configure .NET MAUI Windows application in the background

Tags: winforms, razor, maui

How do I configure a .NET MAUI application to run in the background and be displayed in the list of running services, with the possibility of adding button actions?

How to show the first image, I wanted it to be displayed in this area and that I could click on it and display custom buttons (one of these buttons would open a window, an application window with Razor)
.
With native Windows forms, I saw that NotifyIcon and ContextMenuStrip are used, but I can't find documentation on how to implement these features with .NET MAUI Windows.

I found very little content referring to this.

The only content I found was this link (https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/services/foreground-services) but it fits the topic Xamarim.

Comment: I found that the document you shared is based on android platform. Do you want to use it on Android or Windows?  Can you share more details about the features you want to achieve?

Comment: It would only be on the Windows 10 platform

Answer (score 0):

For this, you can check document [Create Windows Service using BackgroundService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/windows-service?pivots=dotnet-7-0).

Before .NET Core and .NET 5+, developers who relied on .NET Framework could create Windows Services to perform background tasks or execute long-running processes. This functionality is still available and you can create Worker Services that run as a Windows Service.

In this tutorial, you'll learn how to:

- Publish a .NET worker app as a single file executable.
- Create a Windows Service.
- Create the BackgroundService app as a Windows Service.
- Start and stop the Windows Service.
- View event logs.
- Delete the Windows Service.